# SKPSMTPMessage can't send email if ios 5.0.1

Tags: ios, xcode, email

I used SKPSMTPMessage and it works perfectly on ios 4 and 5.1.1.

However when using 5.0.1, I can't send email.

Log

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'HSK_CFUtilitiesErrorDomain', reason: 'Error writing bytes to stream!*** First throw call stack:(0x342a88bf 0x356c31e5 0x342a87b9 0x342a87db 0x150a9 0x16cd7 0x16133 0x34278463 0x3423d563 0x3423d511 0x3423d383 0x379ae119 0x3793ac69 0x3793abe9 0x3427f31f 0x3427cb03 0x3427c2cf 0x3427b075 0x341fe4dd 0x341fe3a5 0x30ae9fcd 0x327c6743 0x2c11 0x2ba0)terminate called throwing an exception(
```